# Shell scripting to find the delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with three columns, which has pipe as a delimiter. Now some lines in the file can have a "," instead of "|", due to some error. I want to output all such erroneous rows.

Comment: And how far have you come? You want someone to solve this for you or only guide you along the way?

Comment: I have no clue on which command can be used in this case.

Comment: I dont even understand the usecase or problem statement clearly enough. You want to count each character? or each word? If character, what purpose does the vertical delimiters have?

Comment: your question is too hard to understand. you don't even provide a sample output. i deleted my answer. it seems there are people who don't like it.

Comment: Alright, let me explain the use case.

Comment: I have a file with three columns, which has pipe as a delimiter. Now some lines in the file can have a "," instead of "|", due to some error. I want to output all such erroneous rows.

Comment: I hope this one is a valid question and explains the use case.

Comment: @Programmer So basically you want to count the number of pipes ("|") in each line?

Comment: Yes that is one of my requirement. So with three columns, the delimiter count comes to two per row. If any row has less than two or more than two pipe, I want to print those rows.

Comment: Not sure why there is so much down vote. I am getting proper answers from user000001. Thanks user000001. I no where feel the question is invalid. I want to understand for what reason down voting is done.

Comment: You kind of changed your problem statement entirely, from counting characters per row to a new problem statement where we only get the info that every row contains exactly three columns, some with "|" and some with ",". And now you just want to count the occasions of ",":s?

Comment: I changed it because people did not understand my statement. I dint get the right way to explain the same. But in short I wanted to find the erroneous row in a file. Couple of things with it, one was to see if the delimiter remains the same, second one was to see that total characters per row doesn't exceed certain limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of columns with awk you can use the `NF` variable:

```
$ cat file
ABC|12345|EAR
PQRST|123|TWOEYES
ssdf|fdas,sdfsf
$ awk -F\| 'NF!=3' file
ssdf|fdas,sdfsf
```

However, this does not seem to cover all the possible ways the data could be corrupted based on the various revisions of the question and the comments.

A better approach would be to define the *exact* format that the data must follow. For example, assuming that a line is "correct" if it is three columns, with the first and third letters only, and the second numeric, you could write the following script to match all non conforming lines:

```
awk -F\| '!(NF==3 && $1$3 ~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ && $2+0==$2)' file
```

Test (notice that only the second line (which is conforming) does not get printed):

```
$ cat file
A,BC|12345|EAR
PQRST|123|TWOEYES
ssdf|fdas,sdfsf
ABC|3983|MAKE,
sf dl lfsdklf |kldsamfklmadkfmask |mfkmadskfmdslafmka
ABC|abs|EWE
sdf|123|123
$ awk -F\| '!(NF==3&&$1$3~/^[a-zA-Z]+$/&&$2+0==$2)' file
A,BC|12345|EAR
ssdf|fdas,sdfsf
ABC|3983|MAKE,
sf dl lfsdklf |kldsamfklmadkfmask |mfkmadskfmdslafmka
ABC|abs|EWE
sdf|123|12
```

You can adapt the above command to your specific needs, based on what you think is a valid input. For example, if you wanted to also restrict the length of each line to 50 characters, you could do

```
awk -F\| '!(NF==3 && $1$3 ~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ && $2+0==$2 && length($0)<50)' file
```

Comment: Your script worked fine, but what if the input file is something like shown below:

Comment: ABC|3983|MAKE, Here the "," at the end is also an error for me.

Comment: @Programmer You could make a second pass with this script: `awk -F'[|,]' 'NF!=3' file`

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem. With above approach, I get only the rows which ends with ",".

Comment: For example: If i have two rows ABC|12345,EAR and PQRST|123|TWOEYES, With the command mentioned  by you, I get only second row.

Comment: @Programmer That's why I said a *second pass*. Use the first one to find lines that are missing pipes, and the second one to find stray commas (and pipes)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input, I got you.

Comment: Now the second thing I want here is to find the count per row. The use case here is, by some error the entries in the file may go wrong and unnecessary data might come into the file. So I want to restrict per row total digits as 50. Can I do the same?

Comment: @Programmer [lurker's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32336985) (now deleted) gives you that: `awk '{ if (length($0) > 50) print length($0), ": ", $0 }' file`

Comment: Thanks for your time and valuable input. All my queries are addressed :)

Comment: user000001, I am not able to do the second pass as mentioned earlier. That is because when there is an error, there can be anything (its not only commo), there can be any other special character. Any way out?

Comment: Does the grep (other answer) help you? Searching for ABC|3983|MAKE, can be done with `egrep "^$n$p$n$p$n,$" input`

Comment: @Programmer I made an edit to the answer with some more scripts. Maybe one of them suits your need.

Comment: @Walter A - it will help to some extent, but not always. I will think of this solution when I face some other issue.

Comment: @user000001 - I will try your edited answer and get back to you. Currently I have implemented your earlier logic itself, assuming that there wont be any row which has all pipes and ends with some other delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use grep, it is more complicated:

```
egrep "\|.*\|.*\|" input
echo No pipe
egrep "^[^\|]*$" input
echo One pipe
egrep "^[^\|]*\|[^\|\]*$" input
echo 3+ pipe
egrep "\|[^\|]*\|[^\|\]*\|" input
```

Before combining the greps, first introduce new variables
p (pipe) and n (no pipe)

```
p="\|"
n="[^\|]*"
echo "p=$p, n=$n"
echo No pipe
egrep "^$n$" input
echo One pipe
egrep "^$n$p$n$" input
echo 3+ pipe
egrep "$p$n$p$n$p" input
```

Now bring all together

```
egrep "^$n$|^$n$p$n$|$p$n$p$n$p" input
```

Edit: The comments and variable names were about "slashes", but they are pipes (with backslashes). That was a bit confusing.