# Shell scripting query

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

Re-framing [Shell scripting to find the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336616/shell-scripting-to-find-the-delimiter):

Given below is my input file:

```
ABC|123|E
NNN|106||E
ORC|244|E
BLU|513|N
ASD|164,E
LMS|216,E
ANO|18,E,
MAY|393|E,
```

From the above file, erroneous rows that I expect out of my script are

```
NNN|106||E
ASD|164,E
LMS|216,E
ANO|18,E,
MAY|393|E,
```

I have tried using **awk -F\| 'NF!=3' file** (suggested by user000001). Below output I get:

```
NNN|106||E
ASD|164,E
LMS|216,E
ANO|18,E,
```

So that last line which is having **MAY|393|E,** is missed with this command.

I want the last line as well, since it has "," at the end. Also I cannot assure that it will be "," all the time. So need something generic. Some check like if my file ends with alphanumeric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk to the rescue

```
awk -F"|" 'NF!=3 || match($0,"[,]")'
```

you can add other delimiters to the regex charset.

Comment: Is there any other way, by not specifying the "," as one of the delimiter? As I mentioned earlier, I am not sure what else it can contain. Anything generic? "|" will always be there, and I have no issue with awk -F"|" 'NF!=3. My only problem is with the row ending with ",". As it wont be "," always.

Comment: you need to know what a valid field is and what can be a delimiter.  For example if ";" can be a delimiter that should be counted you can change the regex to `[,;]`

Comment: Thanks I will check that out.